# Textarea Preview Div

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to script a textarea preview (like stackoverflow) that shows in a div automatically. I have created a script, but it does not seem to be working. If anybody could help me out with the script in HTML and JavaScript I'll be greatfull.

Like this in the picture:
http://i49.tinypic.com/282qpft.jpg

Script that does not seem to be working:
http://jsbin.com/ufeqoj

Comment: what is your question exactly? You may need to share some code

Comment: I am trying to create a Div that shows the textarea value without clicking any submit buttons, In HTML and JavaScript only. Iv also edited my script in my main post.

Comment: @user1608656 Do you want to show whatever is typed in the textarea in the div below it?

Comment: @user1608656 Can you not use Jquery?

Comment: 2 the same question on 1 day? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018727/preview-textarea-div-not-working

Answer (score 2):

Your question is vague, but maybe a few pointers will help.

- You'll want to update your target `div` every time the user types a character. This is the `onkeyup` handler (or `onkeydown`, depending on your intended UX - probably the former).
- Do you want to retain any HTML your user enters in the text area? If so, you'll want to update the `innerHTML` property of your target `div`. If you want to update just the *text*, change the `innerText` property.

A quick and dirty example using jQuery:

```
$("textarea#my_input").bind('keyup', function() {
    $("div#target").text($(this).val());
}
```

As requested, in vanilla JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("my_input").onkeyup = function() {
    document.getElementById("target").innerText = this.value;
}
```

Comment: Ok - Thank You, but could you make that into JavaScript?

Comment: I've updated the answer with some regular JS. Remember, though: jQuery is awesome.

Comment: Note about your original code: you shouldn't define event handlers *inside* the HTML element, though, that's bad practice. You should define them in JavaScript, when you're sure the DOM is loaded. Look into jQuery and the `ready()` handler (jQuery makes it easy) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show whatever is typed in the `textarea` in the `div` below it.

You can work with `Jquery` `.keypress()` function.

**[Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v2sZS/)**.

This is just a starting point.You can alter it to suit your requirements.

For further reference **[Jquery .keypress()](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/)**

Comment: @user1608656 your sample is working. what's wrong ? are you using old browser or IE ?