# Preview Textarea Div not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a Textarea Preview Div.
I have scripted this code but it does not seem to be working, If anyone could help me out, I'll be greatfull. I only want to use HTML & JavaScript for this.

Script that does not work: 
http://jsbin.com/uduxim

Comment: 2 the same questions in 1 day? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018279/textarea-preview-div

Answer (score 1):

Your script tag is wrong:

```
<script type="javascript">
```

It should be this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

[Working version](http://jsbin.com/uduxim/9/)

Comment: That's because Firefox doesn't support innerText. You can use innerHTML instead: http://jsbin.com/uduxim/17/

Comment: <script> does not need a type attribute